# Multiple entry point in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, entry-point

I want to use multiple entry point for login like `'/user/login'` & `'/admin/login'`. I am bit confused about this. Should I use separate files for this, or IS there any way where I can use multiple entry point using the same file? I am using **react.js**

Comment: You only need a single entry point. Check out https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[React Router 4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) is a great router for React that allows you to configure paths like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/user/login" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/admin/login" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/blueberry/login" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/user/signin" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/admin/signin" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/blueberry/signin" component={LoginComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can also use [RegEx](https://pshrmn.github.io/route-tester/#/) to simplify:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/(user|admin|blueberry)/(login|signin)"
      component={LoginComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```